# Ввод двумерного массива, с введеным количеством элементов

Tags: python, python-3.x

На ввод получаю данные:

```
2 
11 22
33 44
```

Как создать массив, чтобы он делал количество строк, которое указано в 1 строчке, а заполнял эти строки, как в следующих, то есть: `[[11, 22], [33, 44]]`?

Comment: А сами данные поступают в виде одномерного массива или это не важно?

Comment: Проблема в том, что мне хочется за 1 ввод создать массив, тоесть не сначала ввести 2, а потом только 11,22 и тд, а сразу скопировать.

Comment: В код, указанный в моем ответе, можно одной вставкой вставить данные и они разобьются. Только это должно быть не одной строкой, а как указано в вашем примере. Если надо одной строкой - укажите это дополнительно.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [3]: [input().split() for _ in range(int(input()))]
2
1 2
3 4
Out[3]: [['1', '2'], ['3', '4']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял:

```
b = int(input())
a = []
for num in range(b):
    a.append([])
    i = input().split()
    for r in range(len(i)):
        a[num].append(i[r])
print(a)
```

Ввод:

```
2 # 1 тест
11 22
33 44

2 # 2 тест
11 22 33
44 55 66
```

Вывод:

```
[['11', '22'], ['33', '44']] # 1 тест
[['11', '22', '33'], ['44', '55', '66']] # 2 тест
```

Answer (score -1):

```
s0 = '''2 
11 22
33 44'''
(n, s1) = s0.split('\n', 1)
li = map(str.split, s1.split('\n', int(n)))
print(list(li))  # [['11', '22'], ['33', '44']]
```